# How correctly use is_reference?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have simple code for illustration of the problem:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T val){
    cout << boolalpha << std::is_reference<T>();
}

int main() {

    int x = 1;
    foo( std::ref(x) ); //output: false
    return 0;
}
```

And question is: why result of is_reference() is false despite the use std::ref ?

Comment: A `std::reference_wrapper` is not a reference, it a class type.  Just because it behaves as a reference doesn't make it one.

Comment: So, what is useful use of reference_wrapper, especially in templates?

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` is designed to be a reference-like thing with object-like copy semantics.  It exists to let you do things like have a `std::vector` of "references" or pass "references" to things like `std::thread`'s constructor.

Comment: The biggest use of `std::ref` is using it to wrap objects that are being passed to wrapper function that make a copy of the passed parameter.

Comment: @masterofcyc "So, what is useful use of reference_wrapper" - here's one: you have a `std::vector<ExpensiveToCopyClass> v;` containing a bunch of unsorted elements. You want a *sorted* view of that vector but do not want to modify the original vector. So, you create `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ExpensiveToCopyClass>> v2{v.begin(), v.end()};` and then you `std::sort` `v2` and cheaply get a sorted view of the original vector without the expensive copies.

Answer (score 4):

`std::is_reference` detects references, lvalue (`&`) and rvalue (`&&`) ones.

`std::ref`, on the other hand, returns an instance of `std::reference_wrapper`, which is 
a class type.

Also note that in `template <typename T> void foo(T val)`, `T` will never be deduced as a reference. The only way to make it a reference is to not rely on the template argument deduction: `foo<int &>(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::ref` returns an instance of the class `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.  A `std::reference_wrapper` object has an implicit conversion to `T&`, but it is not itself a reference.